# Airdrop file notification on Mac - missing "open in finder" option

Tags: finder, notifications, preview, airdrop

When I send an image from my iPhone to my Mac for which I preferably use AirDrop, I'm annoyed that the notification doesn't give me the option to open the received file in Finder, only to open the file itself (see screenshot 1). However, in almost all cases I don't want to open the file, but do something with the file.
Therefore I end up either ignoring the notification and opening the download folder directly (in which I then have to find the file) or open the file and use the right click drop down on the Preview topbar title to get to the file location (see screenshot 2). However I find these two workflows quite clumsy and annoying.

Does anyone have an idea of how to get from the notification directly to the file in the Finder? Or is it only me that is annoyed by this?

screenshot 1. [image]

screenshot 2. [image: drop down menu to get to the file location]

Comment: They finally added it in macOS 12.0.1. Yippie :)